# Access variables outside Mongoose query

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm trying to query all users with Mongoose, and pass them into res.render() to be able to display them on the ejs file.

**Here is my code:**

```
const customersView = (req, res) => {

    const emailsArr = [];

    User.find({}, function(err, users) {
        users.forEach(function(user) {
            emailsArr.push(user.email);
        });

        console.log('Inside: ' + emailsArr);
        // I can put res.render() here
    });

    console.log('Outside: ' + emailsArr);

    // But I have to do some more queries here and then send them back all at once

    res.render('customers.ejs', {users: emailsArr});
}
```

However the emailsArr is empty outside of the User.find().

**The console output:**

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
Server started
Connected to MongoDB
Outside: 
Inside: test@test,admin@admin
```

I can put res.render() inside the find() but the problem is I need to have some more query after this User query and then pass all the results to the ejs at once. How can I fix this?

Comment: Use async/await to retrieve the data with User.find() and then update the array of emails and then send it to ejs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the "outside" code is executing before because `User.find` is a callback, so it doesn't execute until it has the users, which is why it doesn't execute until it has the user.

```
const customersView = async (req, res) => {

  const emailsArr = [];

  const users = await User.find({}).catch(err => {
      // handle error here
  });

  //Your stuff
  users.forEach(function(user) {
    emailsArr.push(user.email);
  });

  console.log('Outside: ' + emailsArr);

  // But I have to do some more queries here and then send them back all at once

  res.render('customers.ejs', {users: emailsArr});
}
```

Change the `customersView` function to asynchronous and use await in `User.find`

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly! I did notice that async might be the problem here. I'm having a hard time trying to understand promise as well as async and await